# While processing XML, how to insert a node after a specific node?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Consider the following XML document that I receive and parse:

```
<Courses>
  <Course>
    <Name>Intro to DB</Name>
    <Credits>3.0</Credits>
  </Course>
  <Course>
    <Name>Intro to Programming</Name>
    <Credits>3.0</Credits>
  </Course>
</Courses>
```

If I want to add a new course between two courses or a new element within each course (e.g. courseId). How can I achieve this in Progress? I've given a read to Progress' XML documentation (for DOM and SAX) and found INSERT-BEFORE(), not sure if that can be used to achieve this.

Do I have to use temp-table/ ProDataSets to achieve this?

Comment: The use of temp-table or dataset depends on what you WANT to do. Is this an xml you create yourself or do you get it another way? You can do it with DOM or datasets. SAX will only let you parse xml, not create it. You could really do it with textual file output as well but that might be a strange approach (but simple).

Comment: @Jensd So the SAX-WRITER is not really writing?!? ;-)

Comment: @StefanDrissen You are right of course, I only briefly have worked with the SAX-READER. I _thought_ it was Windows only .... so I really never bothered.

Answer (score 0):

a example with a temp-table and a dataset

the dataset here is only defined for formatting the xml output

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCourse NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "Course"
   FIELD dSORT AS DECIMAL SERIALIZE-HIDDEN // hidden in xml output
   FIELD Name AS CHARACTER
   FIELD Credits AS DECIMAL
   FIELD NEWFIELD AS CHARACTER
                               
   INDEX SORT dSORT ASCENDING. // this index for sorting the xml output Course
                                 

DEFINE VARIABLE cxml AS LONGCHAR  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iCnt AS INTEGER    NO-UNDO.

// DEFINE DATASET only for xml-node-name
DEFINE DATASET ds 
   XML-NODE-NAME "Courses"  FOR ttCourse.

cxml = "<Courses>
  <Course>
    <Name>Intro to DB</Name>
    <Credits>3.0</Credits>
  </Course>
  <Course>
    <Name>Intro to Programming</Name>
    <Credits>3.0</Credits>
  </Course>
</Courses>".

TEMP-TABLE ttCourse:READ-XML ("LONGCHAR", cxml, "MERGE",  "", FALSE, ?, ?). 

// for sorting output use field dsort
FOR EACH ttCourse WHERE ttCourse.DSORT = 0:
    iCnt = iCnt + 1.
    ttCourse.DSORT = iCnt.
END.

// insert a record in the middle
CREATE ttCourse.
ASSIGN
   ttCourse.DSORT = 1.5
   ttCourse.name = "test"
   ttCourse.credits = 5.5
   ttCourse.NEWFIELD = "NEWFIELD"
   .
  
DATASET ds:WRITE-XML ("file", "C:/temp/baz/courses.xml", TRUE,?,?,FALSE,FALSE).
```